# How to prevent duplicates when tracking conversions with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, google-ads-api

We're implementing basic conversion tracking in our Rails app to track sign ups, sales, etc. In each instance, the user gets sent to a thank you page after a form submission, which then loads the tracking code for Google Analytics, AdWords, etc.

What we don't want is for the tracking code to be loaded if the user reaches the thank you page by alternate means- e.g. reloading the page, pressing the back button, etc- as it will trigger duplicate conversion events. What is a good technique for preventing this?

Comment: You might be able to handle this with a session cookie. Set a key/value that allows access to the thank you page just one time. Then yank that value out so reloading the page causes a redirect elsewhere.

Comment: @TomL- Thanks, you should have made that an answer

Comment: No worries. I wasn't sure if it was specific enough to be useful. As long as it got you on the right track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by placing a cookie during the registration action in the controller and then clearing it with an `after_filter` in the thank you controller.

This would allow you to only load the tracking code if the cookie was present, then clear out the cookie after loading the tracking code.  Now refreshes will still show the thank you page but won't load the tracking code.

Downside is you would miss anyone that doesn't allow cookies, but you might miss them anyway depending on how your tracking code works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the session's flash for that. Just set up something in the flash when signing up, so the next call (redirection after logging in) will consume the flash and add the tracking code.